# How to compare nested_attributes with find_or_create_by in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I would like to be able to use `Company.find_or_create_by_nip(params[:job][:company_attributes])`.

When I want to create `Job` with nested company form I would like to first check if `Company` with that `nip` exist end then assign it to that new `Job`

*Controller*

```
# JobsController
def new
  @job = Job.new
  @job.company = Company.new
end

def create
  @job = Job.new(params[:job])

  if @job.save
    redirect_to jobs_path,
      notice: t('activerecord.successful.messages.created')
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

*Models*

```
# Job
attr_accessible :company_attributes
belongs_to :company
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

# Company
has_many :jobs
validates :nip,
  nip: true,
  presence: true,
  uniqueness: true
```

*View*

```
# jobs#new
= simple_form_for @job, html: { multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :company do |c|
    = c.input :nip
    = c.input :address_street
  = f.submit
```

Comment: I think you placed `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in wrong place, it should be in Company model, and is `accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs`.

Comment: But I am creating ``Company`` from ``Job`` form.

Comment: you can create company and job same time on one form of company, check this: [nested form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: My goal is to create Company from Job form. And if that Company exist assign it to that Job object.

Comment: yes, i watched that railscast, but here I want to create nested form from side where is belongs_to association

Comment: so, what is your problem now, view didn't work? if it worked, post your render html for more info.

Comment: Right now when I fill Company nip which exist I receive error ``nip is taken`` but I would like to create Job with that company founded in database

Comment: please post your new job view rendered html, can't help without it.

Comment: you mean this? https://gist.github.com/6dd680a12ac9026121cf

Comment: add this below save method: `@job.company = Company.find_or_create_by_nip(params[:job][:company_attributes][:nip])`, but rails prefer use `first_or_create` method:  `@job.company = Company.where(nip: params[:job][:company_attributes][:nip]).first_or_create`

Comment: yes, i added that before but i still receive ``pl.activerecord.errors.models.company.attributes.nip.taken``

Comment: are you set validate company_id unique in Job model or in database?

Comment: nope, i guess this is related with ``accepts_nested_attributes_for :company``

Comment: hmm, maybe you should try a if condition, set `nip =  params[:job][:company_attributes][:nip]`, `if Company.exists?(name: nip) @job.company = Company.where(name: nip) else @job.company = Company.create(name: nip) end`

Comment: you can write this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try a if condition:

```
nip = params[:job][:company_attributes][:nip]
if Company.exists?(name: nip)
  @job.company = Company.where(name: nip).first
else
  @job.company = Company.create(name: nip)
end
```